# Why do we use a struct pointer inside a structure definition in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Why is the struct pointer repeated again inside this struct:

```
typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *next; /* Why this statement ? */
}
Node;
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague. It's probably for implementing a _linked list_. Google that term. Tell us more details.

Comment: because you wanted...or do you mean "how"?

Comment: Probably to implement a [single linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html)

Comment: @LPs I really doubt that. a `struct` definition inside `main()` can serve no ,meaningful purpose.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I guessed the posted code is due to OP inexperience. ;) OP probably wants to post the struct definition only.

Comment: @LPs Let's not bother what is what unless it is improved. :)

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Probably `struct Node *next;` --> `struct node *next;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive structs are very useful for all kinds of node-based data structures, in this case a linked list:

[image: Node]

Note how `b` is linked to `a` and `c` is linked to `b` via the `next` member.